# Tracking number not shown in shipment email magento 2.4.5-p2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, shipment-tracking

In the shipping email template, I have a code to show the tracking number in the shipment email.

I have the following code in my new shipment template for tracking code :

```
{{block class='Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' area='frontend' template='Magento_Sales::email/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

but when I send shipment mail I didn't get the tracking number in my email.

**Could anyone please suggest to me how can i fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_track" shipment_id=$shipment_id order_id=$order_id}}
```

Comment: I am using block as well layout but both not working and tracking info is not available in shipment email `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_track" shipment_id=$shipment_id order_id=$order_id}}
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='Magento_Sales::email/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}`

Comment: `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_track.xml` file contains `ferenceBlock name="sales.order.email.shipment.track">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Sales::email/shipment/track.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>`